# Exception handling with superclass-java

Tags: java, exception

If I wanted to use a superclass to handle an exception do I still need to use try catch to handle the exception? This is the code for the super class and the class I used to test it. I tried to use the method quotient in the test class but I needed to add a try catch statement to do what I wanted it to do.

```
 public class ExceptionA {




public static int quotient(int numerator, int denominator)
  throws ArithmeticException 
{
  return numerator / denominator; // possible division by zero
} 


}

public class ExceptionTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {


  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
  boolean continueLoop = true;




  do 
 {
     try
     {
         System.out.println("Please enter an integer numerator");
         int numerator = scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Please enter an integer denominator");
         int denominator = scanner.nextInt();

         int result = ExceptionA.quotient(numerator, denominator);
         System.out.printf("%nResult: %d / %d = %d%n", numerator, 
         denominator , result);
         continueLoop = false;
     }
     catch ( ArithmeticException arithmeticException)
     {
         System.err.printf("%nException: %s%n" , arithmeticException);
         System.out.printf("Zero is an invalid denominator. Please try again."
                 + "%n%n");
     }

     } while(continueLoop);

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method throws an exception, then you are either going to have to write the method to throw an exception, or use a try/catch to handle the exception. At some point you will have to use a try/catch, especially if you call the code in your `main` method.

Comment: main can throw an exception just fine

Comment: Is it possible to use a try catch in the method in the superclass or do you need to call it again in the main method?

Comment: You want to use the try/catch where you plan to handle the error. That should be done in the calling method, not the super class. You would want to call the try/catch in the main method.